# Outlook automatically triggers CTRL + SHIFT

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2007

Someone at my office has been having troubles with her Outlook. She informed me that whenever she sends an e-mail, her keyboard language "changes".

I already know that ctrl + shift triggers that glitch. But it's quite a drag for her to have to keep pressing that combination for as long as she works here.

I myself have typed an e-mail on her computer and I watched carefully not to press ctrl + shift. Nevertheless the glitch is somehow getting triggered.

I've looked in the settings of Outlook and the settings of Windows 7. But I couldn't find anything that could possible trigger this event. So I hope that someone has had something similar like this before, and therefore knows what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Within Outlook:

On the File menu, click Options.
   Click the Advanced tab on left side.
   Under Editing options, select Automatically switch keyboard to match language of surrounding text check box.

[image]

[Source](http://officesmart.wordpress.com/2011/08/31/how-can-i-turn-onoff-auto-keyboard-switching/)

Comment: It was not selected as default. And activating it, and typing French words afterwards did not trigger anything. Sorry. Thanks for suggestion though.

Comment: @vascomakker In that case,  on the same Advanced screen, scroll down to International Options. You will see `automatically select encoding for messages`. Turn this off.

Comment: @vascomakker, also, click start, all programs, Microsoft and look under the Language Preferences and make sure there is only the 1 editing language.

Comment: Sorry, it still did not solve the problem. Could it perhaps be the keyboard itself that is faulty?

Comment: I can't answer that but it is easy to test!